# Process numbers in a file

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I have a .csv file in the form (country,exports,imports). The file has about 200 entries. I would like to calculate the export to import ratio for each country in the file and then write the the countries with the lowest ratio to a new file.

The user of the program will specify how many countries to return BUT will only return files with the lowest ratio.

My first issue is how to process my original file, I think if i figure that out I can do the rest.

Keep in mind there are restrictions on what functions I can use. (I can do things like loops, if statements, dictionaries etc.)

Comment: seems like this is an assignment for SO..

Comment: Have you started writing code yet. You say it is a csv file. Read  docs for `csv` standard module. The problem is straight forward. Just read the `csv` module. Post snippets if you run into any problem.

Comment: @haifzhan yeah it is an assignment for school.

Comment: @CPanda Thanks will look into this and get back with any problems